# Prevent app from crashing if no response from website

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering if there was a safer way to handle JSON responses. Here's the code I have so far

```
func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData{
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)!
}

func parseJSON(inputData: NSData) -> NSDictionary? {
    do {
        if let feed = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
            // Success block...
            return feed
        }
    }
    catch {
        //return(error)
    }
    return nil
}
```

And i'm calling this to check if something was returned

```
let returnedJSON:AnyObject

//Network present
if(returnedJSON){
     returnedJSON = parseJSON(getJSON("URL"))!
}
```

However I ende up with the error

> Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

So is there any better way to do this after the error?

Answer (score 0):

A little suggestion

First return `NSData?`(Do not force unwrapping)

```
func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData?{
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)
}
```

Then check if it is nil

```
if(returnedJSON != nil){

}
```

Comment: I get an error that says `Value of type 'AnyObject' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed`

Comment: See the function,you need to change the `getJSON ` to return `NSData?`,should return a optional value.

Comment: I'm currently setting `returnedJSON`, as `AnyObject`. Check my edit

Comment: Change it to `AnyObject?`,because it can be nil